# XPath for spans inside list items following a paragraph

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following doc:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="this one">
            <p><span><strong>Ignore</strong></span></p>
                <p>Text</p>
            <p><span><strong>Header 1</strong></span></p>
                <ul><li><span style="color: #000;">List Value 1</span></li></ul>
            <p><span><strong>Header 2</strong></span></p>
                <ul><li><span style="color: #000;">List Value 2</span></li></ul>
            <p><span><strong>Ignore</strong></span></p>
                <ul><li><span style="color: #000;">List Value 3</span></li></ul>
            <p><span><strong>Header 3</strong></span></p>
                <ul>
                    <li><span style="color: #000;">List Value A</span></li>
                    <li><span style="color: #000;">List Value B</span></li>
                    <li><span style="color: #000;">List Value C</span></li>
                </ul>
            <p><span><strong>Ignore</strong></span></p>
                <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get all the list values under `Header 3`; however, XPath does not find a match after `<p>`

This works:

```
//div[@class='this one']/p/span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']
```

This does not:

```
//div[@class='this one']/p/span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/span
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `strong` doesn't have any `ul` following siblings.

Change

```
//div[@class='this one']/p/span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/span
```

to

```
//div[@class='this one']/p[span='Header 3']/following-sibling::ul[1]/li/span
```

because `p` does have a `ul` following sibling.  Then you'll select

```
<span style="color: #000;">List Value A</span>
<span style="color: #000;">List Value B</span>
<span style="color: #000;">List Value C</span>
```

as requested.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your XPath expression climbs all the way down to `<strong>`, which doesn't have any siblings (it's the only child of its parent `<span>` element). The element with a following `<ul>` sibling is the `<p>` further up.

In general, you have two choices:

- Climb down, then back up:

  ```
  //div[@class='this one']/p/span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']/../../following-sibling::ul/li/span
  ```

  `..` is shorthand for `parent::node()`.
- Use a look-ahead expression:

  ```
  //div[@class='this one']/p[span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']]/following-sibling::ul/li/span
  ```

  Anything in `[` `]` is a filter condition that does not move the current position within the document tree. You can put arbitrary XPath expressions in there. Here we're using it to find a `p` that contains a `span` that contains a `strong` with the given text.

Demo:

```js
function xpath(expr) {
  var found = document.evaluate(expr, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < found.snapshotLength; i++) {
    results.push(found.snapshotItem(i));
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(xpath("//div[@class='this one']/p/span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']/../../following-sibling::ul/li/span"));

console.log(xpath("//div[@class='this one']/p[span/strong[text() = 'Header 3']]/following-sibling::ul/li/span"));
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <div class="this one">
            <p><span><strong>Ignore</strong></span></p>
                <p>Text</p>
            <p><span><strong>Header 1</strong></span></p>
                <ul><li><span style="color: #000;">List Value 1</span></li></ul>
            <p><span><strong>Header 2</strong></span></p>
                <ul><li><span style="color: #000;">List Value 2</span></li></ul>
            <p><span><strong>Ignore</strong></span></p>
                <ul><li><span style="color: #000;">List Value 3</span></li></ul>
            <p><span><strong>Header 3</strong></span></p>
                <ul>
                    <li><span style="color: #000;">List Value A</span></li>
                    <li><span style="color: #000;">List Value B</span></li>
                    <li><span style="color: #000;">List Value C</span></li>
                </ul>
            <p><span><strong>Ignore</strong></span></p>
                <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you repeat in excruciating detail that which I had [***already answered correctly and concisely***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52158461/290085)?

Comment: @kjhughes As for the timing: I was in the middle of writing (and testing) my answer when you posted yours. I didn't just copy you. As for the answers itself: Your answer just says "do this: <code here>"; it doesn't explain why your code works. My answer shows two possible solutions and explains why they work. None of them is an exact copy of your code. Your code may be shorter, but it also does slightly different things than OP's version.

Comment: You answered 19 minutes after my last edit and provided one needlessly longer XPath and a second XPath that shows the same correction I'd already shown.  I'm not saying you copied; I'm saying added no value.  Had your solution come through while I was writing, I'd have stopped and upvoted yours unless I had something new to contribute.  I'm surprised you feel this answer contributes anything new.